# Very, very different results quality using different optimizers (RMSProp vs. Adadelta)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, data-science

I'm working on a model that learns some embeddings using the corresponding Keras layer, and something very strange happen to me, and I wondered if it happened to anyone else:

- if I train my network with Nadam or RMSprop, I get very good results, few epochs.
- if I train my network with Adadelta, and same learning parameters (epochs, batch size), I get something so bad that it doesn't even make sense. Really, really awful. Nearest neighbors are completely off and random.

I have some experience with training neural networks and I never encountered something like that, and I'm wondering what might, theoretically, be the cause of such a difference in results. I get that different optimizers do not converge with the same rate, but getting something *that* different ? It's not even in the same ballpark. There might be something deeper here, but I can't see what. Did something similar ever happen to you ? What could be the reason of such discrepancies ?

Comment: This would be a better fit for https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: ok thanks @dedObed ! Shoud I delete this question and paste it into your link ?